# Having issues with generating different alphabets for a game

Tags: javascript, html

Since Morning, have been having issues generating random alphabets. The issue is the alphabets will automatically be generate even if there are no similarity between them. By default, i should only regenerate the alphabet if they are the same for example a and b. Can Someone explain my issues and how i can improve it ? Thank you so much.

Here is my HTML CODE.

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
var alphabet1 = [2];
var score = 0;
var generate;
function generateseconds()
{
score = 0;
document.getElementById("Score").innerHTML = score;
document.getElementById("Score").value = score;
document.getElementById("alphabet").disabled=true;
generate = setInterval(getalphabets,8000);

}
function getalphabets()
{
var condition = true;
var alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
alphabet1[0] = alphabet[Math.floor(Math.random() * alphabet.length)];
alphabet1[1] = alphabet[Math.floor(Math.random() * alphabet.length)];
alphabet1[2] = alphabet[Math.floor(Math.random() * alphabet.length)];
while(condition)
{
if(alphabet1[0] == alphabet1[1])
{
alphabet1[0] = alphabet[Math.floor(Math.random() * alphabet.length)];
alphabet1[1] = alphabet[Math.floor(Math.random() * alphabet.length)];
document.getElementById("1st").innerHTML = alphabet1[0];
document.getElementById("1st").value = alphabet1[0];
document.getElementById("2nd").innerHTML = alphabet1[1];
document.getElementById("2nd").value = alphabet1[1];
}
else if (alphabet1[1] == alphabet1[2])
{
alphabet1[1] = alphabet[Math.floor(Math.random() * alphabet.length)];
alphabet1[2] = alphabet[Math.floor(Math.random() * alphabet.length)];
document.getElementById("2nd").innerHTML = alphabet1[1];
document.getElementById("2nd").value = alphabet1[1];
document.getElementById("3rd").innerHTML = alphabet1[2];
document.getElementById("3rd").value = alphabet1[2];
}
else if (alphabet1[0] == alphabet1[2])
{
alphabet1[0] = alphabet[Math.floor(Math.random() * alphabet.length)];
alphabet1[2] = alphabet[Math.floor(Math.random() * alphabet.length)];
document.getElementById("1st").innerHTML = alphabet1[0];
document.getElementById("1st").value = alphabet1[0];
document.getElementById("3rd").innerHTML = alphabet1[2];
document.getElementById("3rd").value = alphabet1[2];
}
else if (alphabet1[0] != alphabet1[1] && alphabet1[1] != alphabet1[2] && alphabet1[0] != alphabet1[2])
{
document.getElementById("1st").innerHTML = alphabet1[0];
document.getElementById("1st").value = alphabet1[0];
document.getElementById("2nd").innerHTML = alphabet1[1];
document.getElementById("2nd").value = alphabet1[1];
document.getElementById("3rd").innerHTML = alphabet1[2];
document.getElementById("3rd").value = alphabet1[2];
condition = false;
}
}
}

function alphabetcheck1()
{
var alphabet1 = document.getElementById("1st").value;
var alphabetlist = document.getElementById("alphabet").value;

if(alphabet1 == alphabetlist)
{
 score += 2;
}
else if (alphabet1 != alphabetlist)
{
 score--;
}
document.getElementById("Score").innerHTML = score;
document.getElementById("Score").value = score;
}
function alphabetcheck2()
{
var alphabet2 = document.getElementById("2nd").value;
var alphabetlist = document.getElementById("alphabet").value;

if(alphabet2 == alphabetlist)
{
 score += 2;
}
else if (alphabet2 != alphabetlist)
{
 score--;
}
document.getElementById("Score").innerHTML = score;
document.getElementById("Score").value = score;
}
function alphabetcheck3()
{
var alphabet3 = document.getElementById("3rd").value;
var alphabetlist = document.getElementById("alphabet").value;

if(alphabet3 == alphabetlist)
{
 score += 2;
}
else if (alphabet3 != alphabetlist)
{
 score--;
}
document.getElementById("Score").innerHTML = score;
document.getElementById("Score").value = score;
}
function stopthegame()
{
document.getElementById("alphabet").disabled= false;
clearInterval(generate);
}
</script>
<h1 style="font-size:30px"><u>Part 1:</u></h1>
        <table border = "1" > 
                <tr style = "background-color: lightblue;"   >
                    <th colspan ="3" > <h3></h3> </th>
                    <th> <h3> </h3> </th>
                </tr>   
                    
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan ="3" align ="center" >
                    </td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                    
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                    
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                    
                </table>
                <p></p>
                <hr></hr>
<h1 style="font-size:30px"><u></u></h1>
<table>

<tr>
<table border="1" width="600px">
<tr style="background-color:#e9967a;">
<th colspan="3" width="500px"><h1 style="font-size:25px">Part 2:Game</h1></th>
</tr>
<tr height="40px">
<td width="160px" style="background-color:#afeeee;"><b>Your chosen alphabet:</b></td>
<td align ="center" width="160px" height="40px" style="background-color:#afeeee;">
<select Name="Alphabet" id="alphabet">
<option value="A">A</option>
<option value="B">B</option>
<option value="C">C</option>
<option value="D">D</option>
<option value="E">E</option>
<option value="F">F</option>
<option value="G">G</option>
<option value="H">H</option>
<option value="I">I</option>
<option value="J">J</option>
<option value="K">K</option>
<option value="L">L</option>
<option value="M">M</option>
<option value="N">N</option>
<option value="O">O</option>
<option value="P">P</option>
<option value="Q">Q</option>
<option value="R">R</option>
<option value="S">S</option>
<option value="T">T</option>
<option value="U">U</option>
<option value="V">V</option>
<option value="W">W</option>
<option value="X">X</option>
<option value="Y">Y</option>
<option value="Z">Z</option>
</td>
<td align ="center" width="180px" style="background-color:#fff8dc">
<label style="font-size:18px"><b>Current Score:<span id="Score" style="color:red;font-size:25px"> 0</span></b></label>
</td>
</tr >
<tr style="background-color:#00FF00;" height="40px">
<td colspan="3" width="500px">
<button style="margin-left:95px;outline:none;border:none" onclick="generateseconds()">
&lt;Start Game Button&gt;
</button >
<button style="margin-left:90px;outline:none;border:none" onclick="stopthegame()">
&lt;Stop Game Button&gt;
</button>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="80px" align="center" width="100px" class="btn" onclick="alphabetcheck1()" >
<span style="color:blue;font-size:25px;" id="1st">
&lt;1st alphabet&gt;
</span>
</td>
<td height="80px"  align="center" width="100px" class="btn" onclick="alphabetcheck2()">
<span style="color:brown;font-size:25px" id="2nd" >&lt;2nd alphabet&gt;</span>
</td>
<td height="80px" align="center" width="100px" class="btn" onclick="alphabetcheck3()">
<span style="color:fuchsia;font-size:25px" id="3rd">&lt;3rd alphabet&gt;</span>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

                
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate what exactly you want to achieve here and where you need help?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Basically each alphabet has to be unique like different from each other. The issue that I need help is let say 1st alphabet is a 2nd alphabet is b and 3rd is c since all of them is different it should not have to change but it change either the 1st alphabet or the 2nd alphabet instead it should just regenerate the 3 alphabet all together again.